# How to print out react-native version

Tags: react-native

How to print out the current version react-native?, if I write `react-native -v` it just print out the current cli version not react-native version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open your package.json file in node_modules -> react-native, and look  at the top. Should look like this:

```
 {
  "name": "react-native",
  "version": "0.12.0",
  ...
```

The react native version will be to the right of 'version'.